# Consuming .asmx webservice using coldfusion error

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, wsdl, asmx

I am trying to consume .asmx webservice in coldfusion. I can view the WSDL but when trying to access methods it gives me the error: 
`Webservice Operation ... with parameters ... cannot be found`

I have tried to add `refreshwsdl = true` as stated in other similar stackoverflow questions with no luck.

What am I missing?

```
<cfinvoke webservice = "urlhere.asmx?wsdl"
method="LoginRequest"
ReturnVariable ="result"
refreshwsdl="true" >

    <cfinvokeargument name="oid" value="a">
    <cfinvokeargument name="username" value="b">
    <cfinvokeargument name="password" value="c">

</cfinvoke>
```

Here is that part of the WSDL:

```
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://blahblah">
<s:element name="loginRequest" type="s0:LoginRequest" />
<s:complexType name="LoginRequest">
<s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="oid" type="s:string" />
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="username" type="s:string" />
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string" />
</s:sequence>
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you try to create an object first instead of using cfinvoke?

Comment: try createobject("webservice","blah.asmx?wsdl") ... then use cfdump to dump out the object. What methods does it show you?

Comment: Is the web service publicly available? Would help us help you  troubleshoot if it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try with the method described in the below link.

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/ColdfusionMaking-a-call-to-a-Web-Service-with-complex-object-as-input-parameter-1228.php

Comment: Since links tend to break, could you update your answer with a brief summary of the solution? Then it will still be useful to others, even if the link breaks or changes.